# Copy a percentage value from a cell to another

Tags: excel, vba

In the given sheet, I have a sales target achieved %, and a corresponding bonus %.
[image]

I want to check the % in sheet1 column AI, and find the corresponding %.

```vb
For a2 = 3 To lastRowx
    If CInt(x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AI" & CStr(a2)).Value) <= 0.8 Then
        pc = 0.5
    ElseIf CInt(x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AI" & CStr(a2)).Value) >= 1.5 Then
        pc = 5
    Else
        Set n3 = x.Sheets("Payout Curve").Range("A4:A74").Find(What:=x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AI" & CStr(a2)).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        MsgBox x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AI" & CStr(a2)).Value
        'x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AT" & CStr(a2)).Value = x.Sheets("Payout Curve").Range("B" & CStr(n3.Row)).Value
    End If
Next a2
```

It is taking the value as decimal, instead of a percentage.
84% should return 60% but it is detected as a 0.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes percentage values are in fact decimal values and hence excel treats them as such. `%` means nothing more than `*(1/100)`. 80% is just another way to display 0.8. If you work with %values you'll always work with decimal values.

If you have a (decimal) value in a cell and want the decimal value to be shown in the xx% format, you'll just have to change the Cells `NumberFormat` - The underlying value will always be a decimal, but the way it is displayed can be changed.

You could even do this with some VBA code. Changing the `NumberFormat` property in order to display decimals as percent values can be done as shown below:

```
Sub setFormatToPercent(cell As Range)
    cell.NumberFormat = "0%"
End Sub
```

Comment: If your percentage values need more accuracy: the format "0.00%" will show 2 decimal places of your percentage